# 2 CPU and 2 monitor, how to setup so that each CPU uses both monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, multiple-computers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching between multi-computer and multi-screen hardware setup](https://superuser.com/questions/75996/switching-between-multi-computer-and-multi-screen-hardware-setup)

I have two towers and 2 monitors, both are separate systems with keyboards and mouses. At times I need dual screen to compare files etc. How can I setup such a system if I am on computer A, I can use monitor B and A both. If I am on computer B, I used monitor A and monitor B both.

I have one KVM switch. What kind of setup will I need? My VGA cards has only one VGA output each, will I need an extra box, what type of or model?

By the way one way setup is acceptable if computer A can use  both monitors and computer just uses it own.

Comment: I need help with equipment list, what will I need and how will I do it.

Comment: Buy a dual headed KVM.

Comment: @Zoredache, thanks for the tip, did not know it exist. The related question might b of help too. Never thought a pure software solution would exists for this problem. I was digging into hardware.